# How could i Recognize which dropdown in view is changed?

Tags: javascript, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I have four dropdowns in my razor view and then all of them has onchange() method and with it, I call submit method from my form, but I want to recognize in the controller which of this four dropdown user is changed actually.
in view:

```
@Html.DropDownList("drpOriginalStation", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.originalStationsList, new { @class = "dropdown-stations", @id = "drpOriginalStation", onChange = "onSelectedIndexChanged()" })
```

and another dropdown like that and then I have javascript:

```
        function onSelectedIndexChanged(val) {
        document.getElementById('search').submit(val);
    }
```

finally in controller I need to recognize which dropdown is changed?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

as Answer as Jack responds just change this script code like below and then it's working.

```
    function onSelectedIndexChanged(selectObject )
    {
         document.getElementById('changedDropdown').value = selectObject.id;
         document.getElementById('search').submit();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

One way you could do this is add a hidden element inside your form:

```
<input type="hidden" id="changedDropdown" name="changedDropdown" value="NONE">
```

Then in your onSelectedIndexChanged you could do this:

```
function onSelectedIndexChanged(e) {
  document.getElementById('changedDropdown').value = e.target.id; // changedDropdown now equals "drpOriginalStation"
  document.getElementById('search').submit();
}
```

Try modifying your control definition to pass this in:

```
@Html.DropDownList("drpOriginalStation", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.originalStationsList, new { @class = "dropdown-stations", @id = "drpOriginalStation", onChange = "onSelectedIndexChanged(this)" })
```

Comment: does not work because it does not recognize argument 'e' inside the script code.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: It does not work! I don't have post back after change dropdown selected.

Comment: aha, thanks jack! I changed e argument parameter to selectObject and now is working, I will write the answer for other people.